Stripe Payment Component using Laravel 11 and Livewire 3
I have created an Stripe Payment Component in Livewire3 and Laravel 11. I'm using the Stripe/Stripe.php rather than cashier.
I thought I was doing well as the payment is being processed by Stripe and it shows as Successful in the Stripe Dashboard; however I am getting the following error in the log files and displayed on the page just before the payment success page
You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method.
This is my code:
The Component
public $invoiceAmount;
    public $paymentMethodId;

    public function createAndConfirmPayment()
    {
        Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));

        $amountInCents = (int) ($this->invoiceAmount * 100); // Convert to cents

        $paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::create([
            'amount' => $amountInCents,
            'currency' => 'gbp',
            'payment_method' => $this->paymentMethodId,
            'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
            'confirm' => true, // Do not confirm the payment immediately
            'return_url' => route('payment.success'),
        ]);


        if ($paymentIntent->status === 'succeeded') {
            return redirect()->route('payment.success');
        } else {
            // Handle other payment statuses (e.g., requires_action, requires_payment_method)
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.payment.payment-form');
    }

The Stripe JS I have is this
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

    <script>
        const stripe = Stripe('{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}');
        const elements = stripe.elements();

        // const component = @this;

        const cardElement = elements.create('card', {
            style: {
                base: {
                    color: '#32325d',
                    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
                    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    '::placeholder': {
                        color: '#aab7c4'
                    }
                },
                invalid: {
                    color: '#fa755a',
                    iconColor: '#fa755a'
                }
            },
            hidePostalCode: true
        });

        cardElement.mount('#card-element');

        const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        const submitButton = document.getElementById('pay');

        //When the form is submitted
        form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            submitButton.disabled = true;

            // Step 1: Create Payment Method
            const {
                paymentMethod,
                error
            } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
                type: 'card',
                card: cardElement,
                billing_details: {
                    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
                    email: document.getElementById('email').value,
                },
            });

            if (error) {
                // Display error on frontend
                const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                errorElement.textContent = error.message;
                submitButton.disabled = false;
            } else {
                // Step 2: Update Livewire and wait for the state to be set
                await @this.set('paymentMethodId', paymentMethod.id);

                // Step 3: Call the Livewire method to confirm the payment
                @this.call('createAndConfirmPayment');
            }
        });
    </script>

Not sure where in my code I have gone wrong - any help would be apprecicated

I think its this bit of the code
} else {
// Step 2: Update Livewire and wait for the state to be set
await @this.set('paymentMethodId', paymentMethod.id);
            // Step 3: Call the Livewire method to confirm the payment
            @this.call('createAndConfirmPayment');
        }

The paymentMethodId is being set but take some time and the @this.call('createAndConfirmPayment'); is not waiting
